# How to convert Python List of Variable-Type to a Bytes Like Object?

Tags: python, sockets, byte

So I have an array of mixed types that I want to convert to a bytes like object:

```
array = [5555, 'North_Terminus', 4444, 0 , 20%3A47]
```

How would would one go about converting this to a bytes like object, preferably encoded in 'utf-8'? I have looked through the Python bytes() & bytesarray() function however the first must be initialized with agiven size and data (integers) and the latter must be mutable, modified sequence of integers in the range 0 <=x < 256.

Error shown below:

```
    data = bytearray(array)
ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)
```

Comment: UTF-8 cannot encode `5555`, only `'5555'`. It's unclear to me what you actually want. If you want to serialize the whole list, consider `pickle`.

Comment: Also, what's `20%3A47`?

Comment: I think you need **bytesIO** and seralization using **pickle**

Comment: ok thank you, i'll take a look at `pickle`